# Laravel list all storages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'd like to get a list of all storage's configured within Laravel (5.6).

Use case: I have a file-system path, I need to then check if part of that path matches with any storage defined in the system, so I can go ahead and use the Storage facade with the relevant disk.

Google has provided me with little - I have looked!

Comment: `config('config.file.dot.notation.array.value')` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config('filesystems.disks')
```

Thanks Tpojka for the suggestion :)